# Binding excel file to datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to bind excel file to `dataGridView`

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                + "Data Source=E://Org.xls;" 
                + "Extended Properties=" + (char)34 
                + "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;" + (char)34;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            textBox1.Text = "test";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", conn);
            conn.Open();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader(); 



            conn.Close();
```

But grid view doesn't show anything. It doesn't give error either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres how to do it, just need to change the path for the excel file and the reference to the grid.

```
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c://Org.xls;Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;" + (char)34);
    DataSet myExcelData=new DataSet();

    conn.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", conn);
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myExcelData);

    ultraGrid1.DataSource = myExcelData;

    conn.Close();
```

Comment: still giving me the blank view

Comment: Hi guys, what the prerequisites for the client machine (do they have to install Microsoft Excel?) if I bind Excel data to DataGridView.  I'm thinking of using pure text file for saving and editing data, but it's very tedious and difficult to deal with.  Still, if there is no special client-environment requirements, I'm gonna use Excel for saving data, and use DataGridView to import (from Excel) and export data (to Excel).

Comment: What if I only use CSV file? Does the client machine have to be installed with something special?

Answer (score 0):

Change that code

```
ultraGrid1.DataSource = myExcelData;
```

to this

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = myExcelData.Tables[0];
```

Comment: If your responding to an answer already suggested then you should leave a comment