# Do-able in MS Access, can Visual Studio 2010 do it, too?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, dataset

My buddy, an Access guru, demonstrated to me how he could link to an Excel spreadsheet from within MS Access and write a query to get the data he needed in about 2 minutes and have a nice custom report done within a few more minutes.  I was impressed at how quickly he was able to do this with no coding, other than minor changes to his SQL.

Does Visual Studio 2010 have this capability, the ability to just point to an external data source (like an Excel spreadsheet, in this  instance) and quickly process it?  I started a new C# winform program in VS2010 to find out.  I added a blank dataset via the dataset designer with the idea that I could "somehow" add a new data source for the dataset and point it to the Excel spreadsheet.  But, for the life of me, I can't see an easy way to do it (when using "Add Data Source.." option).  I've tried different connection strings, different providers, but I can't get the designer to "see" the data in the Excel spreadsheet.

I should point out that I can do exactly what I'm talking about with code, but I was hoping that there was a "visual" way to do this.  You know, something like Access has.  Just point to the Excel spreadsheet, import it as a data source or link to it and voila!

Anyone have any experience doing this?  This is only for retrieving the data, not writing back to the spreadsheet.  I'm just looking for a way to point the designer to the spreadsheet and say "Here, use this as a data source".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Sort of... This is what I've done to add a connection to an excel 2003 (.xls) spreadsheet visually.

1. In the Database Explorer tab you can right-click on Data connections and do "Add connection".
2. select "others" in Data source and ".NET Framework for data provider for OLE DB" in Data provider
3. In the "Add connection" dialog select "Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider"
4. Enter the path to your excel file in "Server or file name"
5. Click "Advanced" and write Excel 8.0 in "Extended properties"

Done, you should have your connection to excel and build LINQ queries (or whatever else) to it in the designer.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Not as quick and easy as it is in Access, but still easy enough.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208604/binding-excel-file-to-datagridview)

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c://Org.xls;Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;" + (char)34);
DataSet myExcelData=new DataSet(); 
conn.Open();  
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", conn);
myDataAdapter.Fill(myExcelData);  
ultraGrid1.DataSource = myExcelData;  
conn.Close();
```

But IMHO, why would you get data from Excel to Access to "work with it" ? It seems logical to use Excel to work with it.

Comment: Yes, I can do this in the code, as I said above.  I was just looking for a way to do it "visually" much like my buddy did in Access.  I mean, it was incredibly quick the way he just linked to the spreadsheet, typed in an SQL statement and Voila!  I was just wondering if VS2010 had the same functionality.

Comment: Oh, also, this discussion came about because a user asked me to write a program that would extract data from an Excel spreadsheet and retrieve other needed data from a database table.  I wrote the program, but it took me a little bit to figure out how to connect to the spreadsheet (I'd never done it before).  I told my Access buddy about what I was trying to do, and that's when he demonstrated how he could do it in Access pretty quickly.